# Frontend and Database at different hosters

Tags: linux, windows, hosting, vps

I can't find an appropriate hoster for both my Windows frontend (ASP.NET) and Linux database (MySQL). I would like to know how bad it is to place them on different hosters. Will it significantly decrease performance if these two servers will be not in one network (or even in one PC in the case of VPS)?

Let's assume connection between hosters is about 10Mbit/s

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't go there to shave a few bucks off.

Latency is first and foremost likely to be the issue. I think it's more complex than this, but assume that the round-trip time is the absolute minimum overhead you will get.

Plus, is the MySQL hoster letting you (and the world) connecting to the database from anywhere?
Do they support encryption, or do you plan to send your data in clear text across internet?

Comment: Yes. This will take performacne down ridiculously.